# Problem with spanning set and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V=M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$, the set of $2\times 2$ real matrices, and consider the subset $$S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

$a)$ Show that span$(S)=V$

$b)$ Find a subset of $S$ which is a basis for $V$

$c)$ Find a subset of $S$ with $4$ elements but which is not a basis for $V$

Now I understand I'll need $4$ of these matrices to get a basis, and these will need to be linearly independent. However without actually taking off matrices from $S$ and seeing which ones are linearly independent then concluding it spans $V$, (i.e part $b$), I can't see a way to show that the span covers the entire of $M_{2,2}(\mathbb R)$. I've tried trying to get a generic matrix from linear combinations but that didn't get me far. $$a\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}+e\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}+f\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix}$$ Tried expanding that to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the best way is constructing a well-known base from what you have.

Let's name the matrices

$$
a_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\quad a_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad a_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad a_4=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\quad a_5=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\quad a_6=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

For example, you have

$$
\frac{a_1-a_2+a_4}{2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

, and similarly you can build other matrices with only an $1$, that span trivially all the space.

Surely, since $S$ has 6 elements, and a base has 4, you can find some linear dependence between the elements, such as $a_1+a_6=a_3+a_4$, that gives you a set of 4 elements that are not indipendent

Comment: Ah thanks makes sense